# PHP explode a string using a specific word

Tags: php, string, explode, preg-split

Im trying to explode below string using Intel(R) word to get two processor name to a array

```
    Ex- 
    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHzIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz 
    to
    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz
    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz
```

I wrote a code using PHP as below

```
   $str='Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHzIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz';
   $exp=explode('Intel(R)',$str);
   echo $exp[0];
```

But didn't see any out put, can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: 'Intel' != 'INTEL' in PHP.  Look up case sensitivity.

Comment: I would prefer regex to get it.

Comment: @ihsan Good for you.

Comment: it was a typing mistake, corrected that.

Comment: I tried the code locally and there wasn't any problem

Comment: It's ok now, the problem was i only check the value of $exp[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code works fine as written, but since the first occurrence is after the delimiter, it will be in 1 and 2, not 0 and 1.

```
   $str='Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHzIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz';
   $exp=explode('Intel(R)',$str);
   print_r($exp);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] =>  Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz
    [2] =>  Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz
)
```